# How to monitor RPC block responses for token transfers?

Tags: rpc, block, fa2

I am wondering how to effectively monitor for some given address for FA 1.2 and FA 2 token balance updates. Given that the entrypoints to the contract are defined, I'd like to write something which reads in each "block" response from the Tezos node, iterates over all executed transactions, and analyzes the entrypoints to track when one of my addresses had a transaction occur.

This would of course only be feasible if all potential token transfers appear as "Transaction" operations in the block response, with the appropriate endpoints.

An example of a token I may want to track is tzBTC, which does call `transfer` internally - and it does show up in the RPC response.

The other method of doing this would be to look inside the storage of each contract, but that doesn't seem particularly scalable.

Comment: You can use BCD API for retrieving FA1.2/FA2 transfers for a particular account:
`https://api.better-call.dev/v1/tokens/{network}/transfers/{account_address}`

Comment: @MichaelZaikin I would like to avoid using a third party. Although, the method BCD has used is likely what I am looking for.

Comment: Why are people so scared of using third party? It's free. It's open source. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An example of a token I may want to track is tzBTC, which does call transfer internally - and it does show up in the RPC response.

That is the answer, isn't that? :)

---

So, you need to iterate over transactions in a block and check for those where `destination` is `{tzBTC}` and `parameters.entrypoint` is `"transfer"`. Then you need to analyze the parameters. They look like this:

```
"parameters": {
  "entrypoint": "transfer",
  "value": {
    "prim": "Pair",
    "args": [
      {
        "string": "tz1Y77S4EcSQwyUWzAwtYGU6NTtKXbH3VQLg"      <--- from
      },
      {
        "prim": "Pair",
        "args": [
          {
            "string": "tz1ZbokEB5tekbPxyWdo28ugn3UUkbQjguK3"  <--- to
          },
          {
            "int": "119380000"                                <--- amount
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, you can easily extract tokens amount, sender and receiver, and check whether it's you.

**However**, I highly recommend you use existing solutions, like [BCD API](https://api.better-call.dev/v1/docs/index.html), because there are so many pitfalls. Otherwise you will likely shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Right, I think that is my preferred solution, provided I scan all transaction operations, including the transactions which are created by contracts (returned in "internal_operation_results"). 

Thanks for the response, glad to hear my initial idea doesn't have any obvious flaws. Noted that using the BCD API can remove a lot of complexity. I will certainly compare the results that my solution returns compared to their API :).